# Testing a cell for multiple condiction before calculating value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am working on a workbook that has a formula

```
=IF(ISTEXT(G4),0,IF(ABS((G4/H4)-1)>=0.2,0,1))
```

Now if **H4** has a value of zero I get the Excel error `#DIV/0!`.  I want to use the `ISERROR` formula to replace the `#DIV/0!` with dashes.  Here is my formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(G4/H4),"--",(ISTEXT(G4),0,IF(ABS((G4/G4)-1)>=0.2,0,1)))
```

Is this possible or do I need another formula to do what I need?

If **G4** has a text value place a "0" in **I4**,
   or if the calculation results in an error place "--" in **I4**, else do formula `IF(ABS((G4/H4)-1)>=0.2,0,1))`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(G4),0,IFERROR((ABS((G4/H4)-1)<0.2)*1,"--"))
```

If `ABS((G4/H4)-1)>=0.2` is TRUE, then `ABS((G4/H4)-1)<0.2` will be FALSE and vice versa.

Reversing the logic like that and turning the `TRUE` into `1` and `FALSE` into `0` is what `(ABS((G4/H4)-1)<0.2)*1` does.

Comment: Is it `IFERROR` or `ISERROR`?

Comment: @ADTC It's `IFERROR`.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work -

`=IF(ISTEXT(G4),0,IF(ISERROR(ABS((G4/H4)-1))=1,"--",IF(ABS((G4/H4)-1)>=0.2,0,1)))`